# Android Horizontal oriented LinearLayout - how to know how many TextViews will fit?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view

My Idea is adding TextViews with rounded corners background to a horizontal LinearLayout, so if next one wouldn't fit - I will add TextView to another LinearLayout below.

Is there a way to do so? I know it sound like a custom view, but I would like not to bother as much  - to adjust height, make click area calculations istead of simple clickListeners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a recyclerview using a flexbox layout https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout with `flexWrap` turned on.

You could also use is in a static layout as well.

With `flexWrap` it does all the calculations to see if the "item" can fit on a line and if not starts a new line.

Many examples on the github page.

Comment: this is exactly the thing I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could keep adding text views in linear layout while checking if newly added text view is outside of linear layout horizontal boundaries, if it is you could remove it from linear layout and add it in new one but I see no reason why you would want to do that.